# CucumberTests java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory

Tags: java, cucumber

I have windows 10 and using cucumber version 1.2.5

I have the following in the TestRunner

```
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"},

        features = {"src/test/resources/features"})
```

However I am getting this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: C:\Users\myuserid\Int_workspace\myprojectname\src\test\resources\features
```

Please it is giving fullpath name (giving userName and workspace name and projectName)...Somehow I have setting and properties somewhere that is causing this issue.   I have tried all recommendation on the internet but none is working...

Comment: "I have tried all recommendation on the internet but none is working" list some recommendations you have tried.

Comment: Change the version. Moved it up and down  to 1.2.0 and 1.2.2 1.2.3  Delete .M2 and regenerate the Maven..interesting is that eventhough the test runner is giving the classpath  (src/test/resources/feature) I am getting the fullpath in the error starting with C disk..

Answer (score 3):

1. Try adding **only Feature folder name** in "features" instead of the full folder path.

EX:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format = {"pretty", "html:target/Destination"},
        features = "Feature", 
        glue={"stepDefinition"})

public class TestRunner {

}
```

[image]

2. The above solutions may work for **Cucumber version 1.2.2**.

In your case, if it is not working try to **downgrade the Cucumber Lib version from 1.2.5 to 1.2.2**

Comment: Did that   features = {"features"})  But  the error still is the full path name :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: C:\Users\myuserid\Int_workspace\projectfolder\src\test\resources\features

Comment: why are you adding {  }  quotes???

Comment: this will be useful only, if you are adding multiple parameters, isn't it??

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have added the correct path. If path is correct then check the jar you have added to the project. Jar version mismatch can lead to this problem. I am using `cucumber 1.2.4` and it is working fine.
Please check with this,

```
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty"},
    features = {"src//test//resources//features//"})
```

Check the permissions to the folder also.